# Understanding N-MOSFET-based 5 V->3 V level shifter

Tags: mosfet, level-shifting, nmos

Is there a simple way to know if a transistor is open or closed that doesn't involve writing equations and assuming that the transistor is open (passing current) and then by math finding out if it's not? That's how I used to analyze circuits in exams.

It looks like a simple circuit but I can't relate this to the N-MOSFET equations which I learned back in University, at least the basic one that shows if the transistor is closed or open (for example: VGS < VT).

Now I'm an engineer and I would love some more straightforward approach. How do I find out whether the N-MOSFET is working in terms of considering VGS, VDS, and VT?

I'm having a hard time deciding which side is drain and which side is source.

In this example, when we apply 5 V to the right side (high-voltage side)  the voltage on the left side is 3.3 V, what is the simplest way to explain this, considering basic logic that involves VGS, VDS, and VT?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In electronics, when we say "open" we mean "open-circuit" and not passing current. If this were a question about hydraulics then "open" would mean passing fluid freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side is lower voltage side so it must be Source and the higher voltage right side must be Drain. It is also apparent from the FET symbol.

When 3.3V source side is pulled low, Vgs is 3.3V so FET conducts and 5V drain side is pulled low, current flows from drain to source.

When 5V drain side is pulled low, the FET substrate diode (not shown in your FET symbol) is forward biased and it pulls source low, but also Vgs is nearly 3.3V so FET turns on and source voltage is nearly 0V.

When neither side is pulling low, both resistors keep their respective side high, source is 3.3V, drain is 5V, Vgs=0V so FET is off.

There are also many websites that describe the operation in more detail.

Comment: Thank you. I understand both cases you discussed. My confusion was about the case when no side is pulling low. Why we get 3.3V  on left side?

Comment: @Xhero39 I updated the answer. I hope it explains it.